# Does the law of independent assortment apply to homologous chromosomes or alleles, or both?

Tags: genetics, gene, meiosis, allele

My textbook is giving me two definitions

---

**1st def**: "random orientation of homologous chromosomes at the metaphase plate in meiosis 1."

**2nd def**: "alleles for one gene separate into gametes independently of alleles of any other gene (only if genes are on non-homologs or very far apart on same chromosome)."

---

It's kind of hard to explain but here are my thoughts on this:

It seems to me that the **1st definition** is exclusively taking a look at each pair of homologous chromosomes:  It looks like it is talking about alleles on certain homologs themselves and how there's 50% chance that a gamete will get a paternal and maternal allele of a gene after anaphase I.

And I'm guessing that the **2nd definition** is an extension of the first by comparing gene assortment in all the homologous chromosomes:
It looks like it is primarily talking about the genes that are on each pair of homologous chromosome and how they (the genes) separate independently of each other (because they are on different homologs) *in addition* to the "random orientation of homologous chromosomes".

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Check out these answers to other questions: [one](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23994/what-is-independent-assortment/23998#23998) [two](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66470/how-do-parents-give-their-offspring-a-chromosome/66480#66480)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is 'independent assortment'?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23994/what-is-independent-assortment)